# SharePoint Migration 2013 to 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

The system relate path is not changed after migration.

For Example:For SP2013 the system related path is 15 
Here we are getting same 15 hive location for SP2016 also(after migration)

Its need to change right.....Why isn't changed ?????Its supposed to be a 16 Hive Right...

Because of that I am getting List Template error while Creating the List and Creating the Library,The SharePoint Default Features are not working Because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, that you didn't follow the migration path exactly. How did you do the migration? Setting up another machine, installed SP2016 and moved the content database? Follow this step by step guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/upgrade-and-update/create-the-sharepoint-server-2016-farm-for-a-database-attach-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

> The reason they did this was to not break compatibility with v15 sites
>   (which is what SharePoint 2016 continues to use... v15 mode). The
>   virtual directory in IIS simply redirects /15/ to the physical path of
>   the 16 hive.
>
> Furthermore there's no compatibility level available in 2016 (yes the
>   switch is there, but there's no point). All sites are v15 and there is
>   no backwards compatibility with v14.5. This was for ease of migration.
>
> This was essentially a feature for Microsoft and is why all sites must
>   be in v15 compat mode prior to upgrading to 2016.
>
> The _layouts/16 doesn't work because it doesn't exist nor does it need
>   to exist. The virtual directory points _layouts/15 -> \Program
>   Files\Common Files...\16. You can look at this in IIS.

Reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/68547ab9-4c8f-423f-911f-ef926ad7a2e2/layouts-strategy-changed-again-in-sp2016?forum=SP2016